# How to use global constants in AngularJs constant

Tags: angularjs

How to use Global constants in app configuration constants.

In Constant.js

```
var ConstantAPI = {
  baseUrl: "http://localhost:4200",
}
```

In appConfiguration.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    myModule.constant('appConfiguration', {
        getEmployee : ConstantAPI.baseUrl + '/getEmployee',
})();
```

**Error**: ConstantAPI is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Why not define it in the constant itself. It should be something like this,

```
var myModule = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.constant('ConstantAPI ', {
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:4200",
});

app.provider('appConfiguration', ['ConstantAPI', function(ConstantAPI) {
   getEmployee : ConstantAPI.baseUrl + '/getEmployee',
}]);
```

Comment: The ConstantAPI should be in In Constant.js file only. because i'm using in different places. can you get me solution please

Comment: in that case you need to define as a json and use http.get to get the values

Answer (score 0):

You have to define constants in a separate file as follows.

```
var MyApp= angular.module("myapp");

MyApp.constant("ConstantAPI",
{
  baseUrl: "http://localhost:4200",      
});
```

[Check this Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/A0y3wcx84rCaCdHb4Dg5?p=preview)